# How do I get my box 3 to align to the right of box 2?

Tags: html, css, css-float, inline

I am trying to get my "this is box 3" to align to the right of "this is box 2" all inside the parent container. Box 3 and Box 2 should overlap and be next to each other?   I have tried to use "display: inline; however that does not do anything. Any advice would be appreciated?

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.box1 {
  height: 50%;
  width: 90%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.box2 {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.box3 {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1"> this is box 1 </div>
  <div class="box2"> this is box 2 </div>
  <div class="box3"> this is box 3 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `float: left` to `.box2` and `marign-top: 10px` to `.box3`:

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.box1 {
  height: 50%;
  width: 90%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.box2 {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: left;
}

.box3 {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1"> this is box 1 </div>
  <div class="box2"> this is box 2 </div>
  <div class="box3"> this is box 3 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: flex` with `flex-wrap: wrap` on the `.container`:

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.box1 {
  height: 50%;
  width: 90%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.box2,
.box3 {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
}

.box2 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.box3 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1"> this is box 1 </div>
  <div class="box2"> this is box 2 </div>
  <div class="box3"> this is box 3 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: While that works great in browsers that support `flex-wrap`, there are other, better supported ways to accomplish this.

Comment: It's 2019 - Unless you need to support IE 10 or below, flexbox is a better solution.

Comment: I was thinking more about older Android devices. What, in your opinion, makes Flex better for this?

Comment: Flexbox is a layout solution, unlike `inline-blocks` or floats.

Comment: You have a point. Floats weren't intended to be used for layout to the extent they have been. So you're an idealist? I'm a pragmatist.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```css
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        html {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        *,
        *:before,
        *:after {
            box-sizing: inherit;
        }
        .container {
            width: 300px;
            height: 600px;
            border: 5px solid black;
            padding: 20px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .box1 {
            height: 50%;
            width:100%;
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding-top: 10px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .box2 {
            height: 50%;
            width: 50%;
            border: 1px solid blue;
            text-align: center;
            float: left;
        }
        .box3 {
            height: 50%;
            width: 50%;
            text-align: center;
            border: 1px solid red;
            float: right;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box1"> this is box 1 </div>
        <div class="box2"> this is box 2 </div>
        <div class="box3"> this is box 3 </div>
    </div>
```